# Show cat output on less exit

Tags: linux, bash, mysql

After viewing a file in `less`, with the convenience of scrolling to the side and searching, I want to be able to view/copy the contents of that file normally in my terminal window without having to run `cat` on it.

Using the `-X` option, the output of `less` is not cleared from the screen after exiting, but anything beyond the right boundary of the window is truncated, and a lot of junk for showing the scrolling gets left behind.

Is there a one-liner or option that would leave behind `cat`-like output after exiting `less`?
The closest I got was with `cat foo.txt | tee >(less)`, which gives me a hard time when trying to quit `less`.

`cat foo.txt | tee /dev/tty | less` works even better than that, but when I use it as a pager in MySQL, it tends to cut off short of printing the whole result table.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the problem with `less -X` is. It seems to work perfectly well on my system, the lines are folded and everything looks fine. Anyway, how about just using `more` instead of `less`? The output stays on screen by default, you can still search in the same way, just use <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Space</kbd> to scroll down and <kbd>b</kbd> to scroll backwards.